# Codeigniter php short tags not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-shorttags

I'm currently following this basic Codeigniter tutorial and the author used this similar code in this view/post_index.php page

```
if (!isset($posts)){ ?>
    <p> No Post to display </p>
<?php
} else {
    foreach ($posts as $row){
?>
    <h2> <?=$row['title']?> </h2>
        <p> <?=$row['post'] ?></p>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

and I get an empty page with this

```
<h2> <?=$row['title']?> </h2>
<p> <?=$row['post'] ?></p>
```

in my source.

However when I use this

```
    <h2> <?php echo $row['title']?> </h2>
    <p> <?php echo $row['post'] ?></p>
```

I'm fine. It shows all my posts. I'm running off wamp  (just downloaded the 64bits & Apache 2.4, 2.2E Version off the website, except I don't see much difference with all the other 4 packages they have....) with 
    Apache Version :    2.2.21
     PHP Version :    5.3.10

What is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: Add a space between `=` and `$`? `<?= $row['title'] ?>`

Comment: codeigniter has config param **$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;** it should be TRUE in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That normally means you don't have short-tags enabled (most PHP < 5.4.0 installations turn them of by default). You'll need to check your `php.ini` file.

Before you enable them, I would suggest reading https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php - there are pros and cons to using the short-tag syntax.

**@IMSoP also makes a very valid note:**

> Specifically, you need the short_open_tag option
>   (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled
>   if using PHP < 5.4. From 5.4 onwards, this setting is still present,
>   but is not needed for the `<?= ... ?>` case, only the potentially
>   problematic `<? ... ?>`

Comment: Specifically, you need [the `short_open_tag` option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled if using PHP < 5.4. From 5.4 onwards, this setting is still present, but is not needed for the `<?= ... ?>` case, only the potentially problematic `<? ... ?>`

Comment: @IMSoP That seems worthy of a separate answer - do so and I will upvote it. Otherwise, I can edit my question to quote you.

Comment: Was just about to edit it into your answer myself, for the general good. As someone else commented on here, "they're just internet points" :)

Comment: we are talking about Codeigniter!

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, I'm not concerned about points either - it just seemed like something that could stand on it's own. Thanks for the assist, at any rate.

Comment: @okok Which is written in PHP. The option you have mentioned elsewhere is *an alternative* for users who aren't able to switch it on in their PHP configuration.

Comment: @IMSoP i think you ned to check here the codeigniter doc http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/alternative_php.html

Comment: @okok Your point is 100% valid, but it is useful to know __why__ the syntax switch is necessary. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @TiesonT. it's usefull if you fix the problem then exaplin how it works in php, otherwise is totally ooftopic sorry :P

Comment: @okok I did read that document. It says "... allowing you to use that syntax even if your server doesn't support it". If you can change the php.ini setting referenced in this answer, then you do not need the CodeIgniter-specific workaround.

Comment: @IMSoP **CodeIgniter will optionally rewrite short tags on-the-fly**

Comment: @IMSoP if we were talking about PHP in general you were right ;)

Comment: @okok Yes, but if you turn them on in php.ini **it doesn't need to**.

Comment: @IMSoP and do you think it's easier editing php.ini especially for a newbie (supposed newbie) ?

Comment: @okok That doesn't make using php.ini "the wrong answer". There are pros and cons to both - for one thing, the CodeIgniter workaround makes syntax errors harder to track down, according to the docs; for another, finding out about php.ini may well be useful and necessary for other PHP problems.

Comment: @IMSoP PHP and Codeigniter reports exactly the same error, please do you use Codeigniter? cause it seems you don't know how it works. Codeigniter has error pages which reports everything if enabled, or logs if you don't want to display errors.

Comment: @okok From the page you quoted youself: "Please note that if you do use this feature, if PHP errors are encountered in your view files, the error message and line number will not be accurately shown. Instead, all errors will be shown as eval() errors."

Comment: nah it shows all, and i don't want to go on anymore, for a simple short tags problem

Comment: @okok Incidentally, the implementation of that feature is here; it's an `eval()` with naive string replacement, so not exactly elegant or fail-safe: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php#L823

Answer (score -2):

if you want to use short_tags, you NEED short_tags, you have to enable them in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = TRUE;`
```

check the doc please [Codeigniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/alternative_php.html)

the documentation  clearly says:

> Note: If you find that the syntax described in this page does not work
>   on your server it might be that "short tags" are disabled in your PHP
>   ini file. CodeIgniter will optionally rewrite short tags on-the-fly,
>   allowing you to use that syntax even if your server doesn't support
>   it. This feature can be enabled in your config/config.php file.
>
> Please note that if you do use this feature, if PHP errors are
>   encountered in your view files, the error message and line number will
>   not be accurately shown. Instead, all errors will be shown as eval()
>   errors.

Comment: @IMSoP yes but pffff, short tags pffff

Comment: If you're using PHP as a template language at all (which I personally wouldn't, but I know many frameworks and CMSes do), then `<?=` as short-hand for `<? echo` seems fine to me. It's only the bare `<?` that was ever a problem, which is why the two were separated out in PHP 5.4

Comment: go in peace, do what you want mehh

Comment: If you weren't so busy being sarcastic, you could have written a helpful answer explaining that CodeIgniter has an alternative to changing the PHP ini setting, which I certainly didn't know.